# Persist data in Display Method

Tags: orchardcms

I nedd to know if there is a way to persist data in Driver Method

```
Display(MyPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
```

Inside the method, I need to do something like:

```
var item = _contentManager.Get(part.Id); 
item.As<MyPart>().Property = 10;
```

and then, update model data with some method like _contentManager.UpdateEditor() or TryUpdateModel()

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Did you try to do just that? There is nothing magical about the Display method, and there is no need to call anything special to persist data. This being said, it's bad practice to have such side effects from the Display method: you're making it lie about its semantics.

Comment: Yes, I did, and it's not working. I know that's not the best way to do the implementation but I can't see other way. Is there a better solution?

Comment: How does it not work? Why do you think you need to persist data from Display? What's the scenario?

Comment: I want to save a json response somewhere and timestamp it. if I have a result from the past 5 minutes, I just use the text that I saved otherwise, I pull it again from the site.

For that, I created one datetime field and store into ContentPartRecord. Now I need to save the current date in that field and persist data.
I really tried just put the value in the content part but does not had any effect. 
I've seen people saying they had the same problem.

Comment: That's weird. Anything in app_data\logs? Still, I don't understand your scenario. Why does this need to be done from Display? Can you explain the actual scenario? What this is for instead of how you think it should be implemented?

Comment: Logs are blank. this doesn't need to be done from Display, I just don't know where else this can be done.
This is for avoid the json's consume every time I access the page. For this I created a field who will store the actual date and consult it before consume the json again. Everytime I do it, I need to save the actual date again.
All of it is done in Display. I think it's bad pratice so, as you say.
Do you understand or is still confuse?

Comment: So it's caching that you're trying to do? You should have said so from the start. Why don't you use the built-in caching APIs in Orchard? s for doing it from a different place, you can choose between action filters, handler events, etc.